# How to handle null columns when performing update mathematical operation on all records in a table in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a price table with four columns as below:

```
id             int
current_price  float null
limit_price    float null
diff_price     float null
```

table with records looks like below

```
id current_price limit_price diff_price
1  18.50         null        
2  null          20  
3  2.25          3
```

my update query below is as follows

```
update price set diff_price = limit_price-current_price
```

So far, I have

```
update price set diff_price = limit_price-current_price where id in (select id from price where limit_price is not null and current_price
is not null)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

How can I handle columns with null values here?

Comment: update price set diff_price = isnull(limit_price,0)-isnull(current_price,0) try this...

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: You should be storing prices using `numeric`/`decimal`, not `float`.  There is nothing wrong with your queries, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: please update the question with more details on how you want to handle the `NULL`s ... ignore rows where `limit_price`  **and** (**or ??**) `current_price` are NULL? set `diff_price = NULL` where `limit_price` or `current_price` are `NULL`?  treat a `NULL` value as `0` (zero) when calculating the difference? something else?  also ... leave the row alone if the `UPDATE` won't chance the current value in the `diff_price` column? ... are there any triggers in place that you do (not) want to fire?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways depends for your desired result. If you want to ignore the columns with null values, your query is wrong. With `where limit_price is not null and current_price is not null` you ignore the rows only when both columns are null.

You should use this query:

```
update price 
set diff_price = limit_price-current_price 
where current_price is not null or limit_price is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL means that a value is either unknown or not applicable. If the current price or the limit price are not given, then there is no difference to calculate, so the difference calculation must result in NULL. SQL does exactly that. Your update statement

```
update price set diff_price = limit_price - current_price;
```

results in

| id | current_price | limit_price | diff_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18.50 | null | null |
| 2 | null | 20 | null |
| 3 | 2.25 | 3 | 0.75 |

just as it should. The answer to your question "how to handle nulls in math operations" is "the DBMS already handles this for you".